# Problem with Refsection

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I can't seem to get the reference within my {refsection}.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

%Point to the bibliography db
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\include{myparagraph}

\end{document}
```

My paragraph file

```
\myparagraph{\fullcite{dante1320}}
\begin{refsection}

\cite{manzoni1827}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
```

I get the first citation (dante1320) right, but the second prints as [manzoni1827]. I don't get any error when I run Bibtex concerning the missing reference. But I got it when I run Latex: `LaTeX Warning: Citation 'manzoni1827' on page 2 undefined on input line 5.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Biber

If you can use `biber` instead of `bibtex`, then this will just work. Change `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber`, and run `biber filename`, instead of `bibtex filename`.

### Bibtex

When you use `bibtex` however, you will get one `.aux` file for each `refsection`, and you have to run `bibtex` on each of these files, not just the one for the main document. Information about this is printed in the log file as well, `biblatex` will write a warning to the `.log` file saying something like this after compiling with e.g. `pdflatex`:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                test1-blx
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Where `test` is the name of the `.tex` file.