# Problem with Refsection if using Overleaf

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, overleaf

I'm using the **Classicthesis** template using *Overleaf* as the compiler. I need a chapter at the beginning of the document with my publications, and the template suggests to use the command *Refsection*, but it seems that I cannot get the reference in my output.

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128196/problem-with-refsection) on TexExchange a similar problem was solved (see there for an example of the code), but the solution proposed there doesn't work on Overleaf. In particular:

1. setting `backend=biber` produces errors in the output
2. in Overleaf I'm not finding a way to run `bibtex` on each of the files .aux separately, as required by *Refsection*.

The error that I get is always of type `Citation 'Feng:2016msc' undefined on input line 13.`

Comment: What are the `biber` errors?

Comment: If you can't provide a reproducible example and you think this is an Overleaf-specific problem, please reach out to Overleaf support: support@overleaf.com. Be sure to provide detailed information about the problem and your project URL for them to take a look.

Comment: Using `biber`, it prints the error `Cannot find 'ownpubs.bib'!`, that basically is a fictitious .bib file linked to the name of the Refsection. In addition, all the other citations outside Refsection are not recognised anymore (this does not happened using `bibtex`).

Answer (score 0):

`biber` is unhappy as it cannot find the `.bib` file `ownpubs.bib`.  This is presumably causing `biber` to abort, leaving no valid `.bbl` to form and thus breaking all citations in the main text.

The optional argument of [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)'s `refsection` environment *can* be used to supply a distinct set of `.bib` files from those called by `\addbibresource` in the main document, if used it must point to existing resources.
However if you only wish to include references already added outside the `refsection` with `\addbibresource` it should be omitted.

Comment: Yes, I need to include include references already added outside the `refsection` with `\addbibresource`, so I'm omitting the argument of `refsection`. However here is the problem: the references I need are not recognised inside `refsection`. As far as I understood, I need to recompile a separate .aux file, but I cannot do this inside Overleaf. Maybe I can use a different strategy? I need a preliminary chapter with my publications inside my thesis.

Comment: @McSenegal You should use `backend=biber`, if that does not work it is highly unlikely `backend=bibtex` will, [`backend=biber` only requires running `biber file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128201/106162)`, which Overleaf should be doing fine.  Right now, `Cannot find 'ownpubs.bib'!` is a clear error, fix it and see if anything else comes up after using "Recompile from scratch", check the `.blg` file `biber` produces.  Without code or more log information there's little else to go on, if you had references working at some point try commenting out changes to localise what broke them.

Comment: @McSenegal to be clear, the reason references outside the `refsection` are working for you with `backend=bibtex` is an artefact of `biblatex`'s limited support for `bibtex` requiring separate compilations.  It's a pretty safe bet that if you run `bibtex` on the extra aux file (which Overleaf may even be doing for you and silently failing), the references in the `refsection` would still fail, fixing with `backend=biber` should be equivalent (and advised) even if the intermediate broken state looks more broken.